# OpenGL Internals: What can disrupt glDrawElements

Tags: opengl

I'm working on integration of a piece of graphics software with the graphics engine to which I have no source code. My software tries to draw simultaneously with a graphic engine using OpenGL. At some points there are conflicts - my glDrawElements (or glDrawArrays) doesn't draw. Apparently the engine sets some OpenGL states that disrupt my drawing. I ensured that GL_VERTEX_ARRAY is enabled just prior to calling glDrawElements. What else could be disrupted by the engine, that has no idea I'm there?

UPDATE: Conflicts are appearing when objects owned by the engine are either drawn or exist off-screen (camera looks away). No conflicts appear when my drawing is the only thing there is on the scene - engine just sets up windows, context, mouse interaction etc.

UPDATE2: I also read the following:

> glDrawArrays is included in display lists. If glDrawArrays is entered into a display list, the necessary array data (determined by the array pointers and enables) is also entered into the display list. Because the array pointers and enables are client-side state, their values affect display lists when the lists are created, not when the lists are executed.

Could it be that GL_VERTEX_ARRAY gets disabled by the time the list is executed?

Comment: Display lists are deprecated in OpenGL 3.1, and have not been in wide use for quite some time. Unless the software you are integrating is very old, it's unlikely that it uses them.

Comment: There's a lot of state that affects the drawing, so this would be a very long list. On most platforms, there are tools that allow you to trace (capture) OpenGL calls while running an app. I believe there are open source tools as well if a tracing tool is not standard on your platform. This allows you to see what calls the opaque code is making, and then you should be able to identify which state changes are being made that look harmful to your own rendering.